# To find out the first occurrence of a property (no need to be exactly matched)

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Can you tell me how to find out the first occurrence of a property (no need to be exactly matched) by using [**Underscore.js**](http://underscorejs.org/#find) ?

I have tried this.But it returns only the exactly matched property.Let's say on my list where it has `townName` like `Rocky Point`.But I need to pick the `Rocky` also.So how can I do that ?

```
var schoolDistrict = _.find(vm.schoolDistricts, function (d) { return d.townName 
== result.data[0].PropertyData.School; });
```

**e.g.**

```
vm.schoolDistricts = [townName:'Rocky Point',...]

result.data[0].PropertyData.School = 'Rocky'
```

Comment: Try `d.townName.indexOf(result.data[0].PropertyData.School) !== -1`. This will check if the string of the townname contains the string of the school name, instead of they needing to be exact. You can add `toLowerCase()` to both strings if you also need to find 'rocky' in 'Rocky Point'.

Comment: @Shilly Your solution is also not working.This is the code snippet.`var schoolDistrict = _.find(vm.schoolDistricts, function (s) { return s.townName.indexOf(result.data[0].PropertyData.School) !== -1; });`

Comment: @Shilly You're correct.I have to use `toLowerCase()`.Then it's working.Would you like to put it as an answer ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OP's feedback:** I have used as shown below and working fine :)

```
var schoolDistrict = _.find(vm.schoolDistricts, function (s) { return 
s.townName.toLowerCase().indexOf(result.data[0].PropertyData.School.toLowerCase(
)) !== -1; });
```

**Another way :**

You could do a primitive check if either string is a substring of the other. You could also make the strings lower case for a better search:

```js
var schoolDistricts = [
  {townName:'Rocky Point'}, 
  {townName: 'Roc'}
];

var searchString = 'Rocky'.toLowerCase();

var res = _.find(schoolDistricts, function(s) {
  var townName = s.townName.toLowerCase();
  return townName.indexOf(searchString) !== -1 || searchString.indexOf(townName) !== -1; 
});

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working for me.This is the code snippet.`var schoolDistrict = _.find(vm.schoolDistricts, function (s) {
                               return s.townName.indexOf(result.data[0].PropertyData.School) !== -1 || result.data[0].PropertyData.School.indexOf(s.townName) !== -1;
                           });`

Comment: @Sampath That's odd. Are you sure your `result` looks like you have written? It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use RegExp pattern to test if the name contains the text, with the `i` flag to ignore case:

```js
var schoolDistricts = [{
  townName: 'South Rock'
}, {
  townName: 'Red Herring'
}, {
  townName: 'Rocky Point'
}, {
  townName: 'Whatnot'
}];

var school = 'Rocky'; // replacement for result.data[0].PropertyData.School

var pattern = new RegExp(school, 'i');

var result = _.find(schoolDistricts, function(d) {
  return pattern.test(d.townName);
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```